# Closures - Common Sense?

Tags: javascript, closures

MDN's [A re-introduction to JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript) article finishes with a discussion of closures:

> a function defined inside another function has access to the outer
>   function's variables. The only difference here is that the outer
>   function has returned, and hence common sense would seem to dictate
>   that its local variables no longer exist.

The article goes on with scope objects and scope chain, etc.   Sounds very sophisticated.  However stepping thru their example script, I see no reason why common sense would fail?

```
function makeAdder(a) {
  return function(b) {
    return a + b;
  };
}
var x = makeAdder(5);
var y = makeAdder(20);

x(6); // returns 11
y(7); // returns 27
```

So, setting x = to makeAdder with argument, 5:

```
x = function(b) {return 5 + b;};
```

so when we now call x with argument, 6, we have

```
function(6) {return 5 + 6;};
```

which returns 11.

I guess my question is: am I missing something?  Closures seem simple.  Why do people get hung up on the concept?

Comment: They are very simple and easy to understand. The *common sense* remark is because variables normally may be expected to only exist to the end of their defined scope. So since the call to `makeAddr` has exited, it would stand to reason that the `a` variable would have been freed. It's because of closures that it is not freed.

Comment: Important to note that `x = function(b) {return 5 + b;};` isn't really what happens. In other words, the function does not get a copy of the value of `a`, but instead has a reference to the variable, so it's really `x = function(b) {return a + b;};`, where `a` is still defined inside the `makeAddr` scope

Comment: The a variable is freed/garbaged.  x = function(b) {return 5 + b;}?  A is gone.  There is only x remaining alive.

Comment: No, that's the point. `a` is not freed. The `a` variable will remain alive as long as the function referenced by `x` remains alive. That's the closure.

Comment: ...[here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u7e0xmw5/) that demonstrates it. I changed your example so that two functions are returned instead of one. The `add` function is the same as your original returned function, and the new `mutateA` function receives a value and mutates the `a` variable. If the functions returned had received a copy of `a`, then calling `mutateA()` would have no impact on the output of the `add()` method, but you'll see that that's not the case.

Comment: But argument/variable, a, is gone.  The article even says, "these scope objects cannot be directly accessed from your JavaScript code."  A variable can vary.  The number 5 is a "double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754 value".

Comment: Closures are simple once you have the foundational knowledge to grok them. Sounds like you have this, hence "easy".

Comment: You can keep saying that if you wish, but it's not true. The `a` variable is not gone. That's the point of closures. The "scope objects" referred to are the internal object that holds the variables. That object can not be directly accessed, except for at the global scope.

Comment: I don't understand a += +n || 0 so I'm gonna have to get back to you.  Thanks for the feedback.  It sounds like you are making an important distinction.

Comment: Just read it as `a += n` or `a = a + n`, which will be the same as long as `n` was given an actual number.

Comment: The nature of closures will be even more prevalent when you do an asynchronous operation in `makeAdder`, like a timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess my question is: am I missing something? Closures seem simple. Why do people get hung up on the concept?

No, you're not missing anything. Closures are simple. You'll have to ask the people who claim they're complicated—to the extent of even writing books on the topic—why they think they are.

What might conceivably be considered complicated is adopting a design mindset  which takes advantage of this simple concept.

Comment: *No, you're not missing anything.* From the discussion in the comments it seems they are missing some subtleties.

Answer (score 0):

I find DOM element creation loops show the concerns best. Notice this code prints buttons with the correct `i` values, but when clicked will show `5` because a new closure was not created capturing `i` at the time.

```js
for(var i = 0;  i < 5; i++) {
  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  var t = document.createTextNode(i); 
  btn.appendChild(t); 
  btn.onclick=function(){ alert(i) }
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

This code creates a new closure that will alert the correct value.

```js
for(var i = 0;  i < 5; i++) {
  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  var t = document.createTextNode(i); 
  btn.appendChild(t); 
  btn.onclick=onClick(i);
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}

function onClick(i) { 
   return function() { alert(i) }
}
```

Comment: All of this is no longer an issue if you simply use `let i` instead of `var i`.

Comment: A key word I see missing in the first example is 'return'.  The MDN example shows the use of 'return' as well.

Comment: Right `let` is great. My point is in showing the confusion for new javascript programmers. In the first example, the button's text is set with `i` and the alert is showing `i`. It is not immediately intuitive that they show different values.